# Cannot convert value of same type

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, accelerate

I cannot seem to call vDSP* accelerate functions. I get the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer<Float>' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<Float>'

Sample code:

```
var m:Float = 0.0 as! Float
var points : [Float]

points.withUnsafeBufferPointer {(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer<Float>) -> Void in
        vDSP_minv(buffer.baseAddress!, vDSP_Stride(2), &m, vDSP_Length(2))
}
```

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: "Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer<Float>' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<Float>'"

Comment: After initializing `points`: `var points = [Float]()`,it compiles fine here.

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting with generics and overloaded my class mistakenly using the `Float` class which caused the strange error message:

```
class bar<Float> { ... }
```